# Global object property modification works from function, but cannot redefine object itself

Tags: javascript, object, closures

How this behaviour could be explained? Why it prints {a:10}?

```
var a = {};

(function b ( a ) {
    a.a = 10;
    a = null;
})( a );

console.log(a); // { a: 10 }
```

Comment: It doesn't print `10` it prints `{ a : 10 }` just as you defined in the function. Oh, you're meaning the `null` assignment...

Comment: Change the local variable `a` to something else, and then it'll work as expected.

Comment: two references point into the same object. when you add property it affect for both references, but when you set one of them to null, you actually change the reference, not the object. So via the original reference which points the object, it prints 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JS, Objects are passed by reference. So when you do `()(a)`, you are passing reference of `a` to function as an argument.

Now this reference is saved in a local variable as an arguments. So when you update the variable, you are essentially overriding the object at that location.

The trick is, when you replace the reference. `a=null`, will update the reference in the argument variable `a` but will not override the object in the reference. So the original object is still available, just not referenced.

After IIFE, when you again log, since the scope of argument variable is over, it is destroyed, and `a` is again pointing to original `a`.

Hence, you are getting `{a: 10}`

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function `a` refers to the local variable passed into the function. Since you chose the same name it is confusing, but see this:

```js
var a = {};

(function b ( c ) {
    console.log('1. c = ', c);
    console.log('2. a = ', a);
    c.a = 10;
    console.log('3. c = ', c);
    console.log('4. a = ', a);
    a = null;
})( a );

console.log('5. a = ', a);
```

It returns null as expected

Comment: You might also want to log both `a` and `c`, before and after the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The `a` inside your function is a different variable than the global `a`. You pass in the value of the global variable `a` into your function which creates a local variable. The fact that you named that local variable `a` just means that it shadows the global variable by the same name.

So it's two different variables, but their values are both references to the object you created. Inside your function you write to a property of that object. Then you assign `null` to the local variable `a`. This only removes this particular reference to the object but the object still exists and the global variable still refers to it, so when you `console.log()` this global variable it will print the object.